# Xamarin build error: defining a default interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

After installing Plugin.MediaManager 0.7.1 in my Xamarin Forms project, the Android build gives me error:

```
java/lang/Object;I)V: defining a default interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 13) for interface methods: com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player$EventListener.onTimelineChanged : (Lcom/google/android/exoplayer2/Timeline;Ljava/lang/Object;I)V  Readings4.Android   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets    2816
```

Tools: 
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.1.6

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No Dex compiler was specified, select D8 Dex compiler in the Android project properties:

[image: Dex compiler option]

In code:

```
<AndroidDexTool>d8</AndroidDexTool>
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly the fix I needed in my project!