# Xamarin build error : defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

After I don't know what I start getting this error which prevents building my Xamarin Forms projects:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       java/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List;: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 13) for interface methods: okhttp3.Dns.lambda$static$0 : (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List;    BeCause.Android C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets    2610

I have tried many things like modifying SDK min and target versions or downgrading okhttp to lower version but the error remains.

Comment: can you try set D8 Dex in android properties, it's work in android Native and I hope it will work in your project too.

Comment: There is one option called Enable MultiDex, it turns on D8 Dex in android properties. With or without it, same error appears.

Comment: @IRONicMAN,From this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57027952/xamarin-build-error-defining-a-default-interface-method-requires-min-sdk-vers, we can see that select d8Dex, right now d8 is offered as an independent package on NuGet:https://github.com/atsushieno/xamarin-android-d8-build